How to Dynamically Update HTML Table Content with JavaScript without jQuery?
I'm building a web application where I need to dynamically update the content of an HTML table based on user input, without using jQuery or any other libraries. I've managed to add rows to the table, but I'm struggling with updating existing rows. Here's the HTML structure of my table:
<table id="data-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Rows will be added here dynamically -->
</table>


And the JavaScript code I've used to add rows:
function addRow(name, age) {
  const table = document.getElementById("data-table");
  const row = table.insertRow(-1);
  const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = name;
  cell2.innerHTML = age;
}


This works for adding new rows, but I'm unsure how to update an existing row's cells with new data. Is there an efficient way to search for a row by one of the cell values (e.g., Name) and update it directly in plain JavaScript?

Use the Table API.

Try this
var findRowByName = (table, value) => {
  return table.querySelectorAll("TR").filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.children[0].textContent == value;
  })[0];
  
}

